# How to provide type safety in a two dimensional type hierarchy?

Tags: c++, inheritance, type-conversion, c++17

Consider the following class hierarchy:

```
class A {};
class B : public A {};
class C : public A {};
class D : public A {};
```

Assume that it is not trivially reducible: B, C and D have at least one pairwise disjunct member definition and at least one shared member definition inherited from A.

Now consider a hierarchy of containers containing pointers to objects from the first one:

```
class AV : public std::vector<A*> {};
class BV : public AV {}; // contains only B*
class CV : public AV {}; // contains only C*
class DV : public AV {}; // contains only D*
```

Again, assume it to be not trivially reducible as defined above.

These classes are supposed to be "containers with features": providing common container functions for their elements and functions along the lines of "get average of ", "does any element satisfy " etc. . Operations on V always assume elements of class  for x in { A, B, C ,D }.

Now the issue is that children of AV provide std::vector functions instantiated on A*, instead of their actual content of B*, C*, D* respectively.

There are three solutions I can see, all with unfortunate drawbacks:

1. override std::vector members in classes [B|C|D]V to cast to the correct pointer type

   - obvious drawback: lots of boilerplate code
2. let AV not inherit from std::vector and instead make [B|C|D]V inherit from the respective std::vector<[A|B|C]*> instantiation

   - obvious drawback: AV can no longer be used for code where only element members from class A are used.
3. do not define [A|B|C|D]V as class hierarchy but as class template, provide implementations per template parameter [A|B|C|D]

   - obvious drawback: loss of implicit hierarchy information, esp. using IDE tools such as Visual Studio -> code becoming harder to navigate

Note that the issue persists if the container were member instead of parent of classes [A|B|C|D]V.

**Is there a better solution to the quandary? If it is idiomatic, how is it called?**

Simplifications for the sake of clarity:

- C pointers instead of the more appropriate std::weak_pointer
- short class names instead of telling ones
- Inheriting from an STL container provides the container function[s|ality] for free, as is the purpose of inheritance.

Providing the STL container as a member instead would lead to implementation of delegates for most of its functions along these lines:

```
class AV
{
public:
  auto begin() { return this->container.begin(); }
  auto end()   { return this->container.end(); }
  /* etc. pp. */
protected:
  std::vector<A*> container;
}
```

Comment: 4. Implement a completely type-safe template. This will result in code bloat, but that's what C++ is all about.

Comment: Do not inherit from std::vector.. Avoid storing pointers (even smart pointers), unless you need polymorphism..

Comment: I think you should **reformulate** the question where you avoid inheritance from `std::vector`. That's a red herring for readers. And as you note it's not essential for your question

Comment: You raise multiple complex issues, implicitly and explicitly. The most troublesome is that this parallel hierarchy can very easily break type safety. Consider `struct A{}; struct B:A{}; struct PA{ A*& foo(); }; struct PB: PA { B*& foo(); };` where `foo` in both `PA` and `PB` accesses the same raw pointer member. Then a `PB` instance can be bound to a `PA&`, and the pointer can be set to point to C, breaking the class invariant of `PB`.

Comment: Another complex issue has to do with construction safety, avoiding 2-phase construction (or worse). This is a well known problem that's addressed in C++ GUI frameworks. Such a framework typically provides one high level C++ widget for each lower level C API widget thingy, i.e. about the same kind of parallel hierarchy as in your question. The main complication you add is the one of a vector of wrappees, instead of a single wrappee, per high level object. Still it looks like the same problem.

Comment: After thinking about, I'm voting to close this as **too broad**. This is an informed vote. I could write a book or two about the subject.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf : If I wrote a composition example vs. the current inheritance based one, would that change anything? I do not feel comfortable inserting legitimation for every odd design decision into the example, when the problem outlined is rather concise, and how it came to be not interesting.

Comment: Added exposition about the intended container use to the question. Mayhap that helps focus.

Comment: @DieterLücking : How to do non-owning containers then? References seem to make it unnecessary hard to sanity check for missed deletion notes from the owner.

Answer (score 0):

That should do it.

```
template<typename L>
class  V : public std::vector<L*> {}; // all members of original AV
class AV : public V<A> {}; // now empty
class BV : public V<B> {}; // as before
class CV : public V<C> {}; // "    "
class DV : public V<D> {}; // "    "
```

If I am not mistaken, no further limitations vs. the original setup should apply.

At this point we are just one step away from @SamVarshavchik 's original comment, which was incidentally the very first activity on this question. Sometimes the simplest answers are the best - and the most difficult to spot.

Comment: Note: I am aware that I might improve this by replacing AV with another template class V and promoting AV to a non-template on the same layer as [B|C|D]V. Editing the question to reflect this would mean to get rid of the confusion about that default template argument though, and I would like to see whether someone can enlighten me about that; within a bit of time I will provide the corresponding edit that would make this answer acceptable.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is an answer to the question. I feel like this information would be better suited in the question as the fourth solution with an unfortunate drawback.

Comment: @Zsar: "*According to cppreference.com this should not be the case*" There's a difference between `AV` and `AV<>`. The former is a template; the latter is a class.

Comment: @Tas : I consider it passing as the necessary modifications can be done via search&replace, without difficult or failure-prone regexes. Arguably, 1-3 could be answers themselves, considering that they _do_ solve the issue at hand, but their arbitrarily defined fitness is too low to consider them. I might actually go with this one (or rather: with base template class V, [A|B|C|D]V inheriting from that, as outlined in my comment).

Answer (score 0):

A `BV` is not an `AV`.  There should not be inheritance there, as there are no useful ways for a `BV` to satisfy the invariants of a reasonably useful mutable `AV`.  Having a (C++) inheritance here is harmful.

This is the old rectangle-square problem, where an immutable square is an immutable rectangle, but a mutable square is not a mutable rectangle.

There are 3 prongs.  Reading, writing and implementation.

An `AV_reader` is a base class of a `BV_reader` (etc).  Non-mutating operations on a `BV` satisfy the reasonabke ore and post conditions of a `AV`, assuming the same is true of `A` and `B`.

For writing, this cannot be the case; a `BV_writer` is not a kind of `AV_writer`.  Possibly it can be upside down: an `AV_writer` is a kind of `BV_writer`, but that again relies on `A` and `B` properties, and those are properties are a bit less common than the read invariants.  Also some extensions (`BV_writer_augment`) won;t be part of `AV_writer`.  The contravariance of parameters may get you this for free.

On the implementation side, using a `vector<A*>` to store a `vector<B*>` and wrapping it in a myriad of casts innand out is error prone and a pain.

The conclusion is:

You want covariant reading, contravariant writing, (I think I got those two names right: I sometimes reverse them) and a template CRTP-like implementarion system that does type checking storing the actual underlying vector without forcing no casts.

This does not match the C++ default polymorphic inheritance pointer system.  So don't use C++ pointer polymorphism inheritance.

Now the problem is that the proper solution is hard, and takes some boilerplate.  But it is the right way to do it.

Comment: Mmh. Mayhap I underspecified. Mayhap names help. Assume AV were a "UnitList", BV a "LandUnitList"; all functions of AV must be available in BV, some are virtual and overridden but most just inherited. In that scenario, A would be "Unit" and B would be "LandUnit". LandUnit would have additional values, but all the values of unit, all the functionality of Unit. Both Unit->LandUnit and UnitList->LandUnitList are certainly valid inheritances, insofar that any latter is always (and is used as) a fully functional former.

Comment: @zsar that violates [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) if you can write elements or add elements to `AV`.  Adding a `LandUnit` to a `UnitList` that is actually a `WaterUnitList` is an example of a symptom of this violation.  A LandUnit can be a Unit, but a LandUnitList is not a UnitList *if there are write-like operations*, because a LandUnitList's write precoditions (source is a LandUnit) are stricter than UnitList write preconditions (source is a Unit).  A ReadOnlyLandUnitList is a ReadOnlyUnitList.

Comment: Amusingly, a WriteOnlyUnitList is a WriteOnlyLandUnitList, as the preconditions on WriteOnlyUnitList are *weaker* than a WriteOnlyLandUnitList.  If you are unfamiliar with this trick, you will want to sit back and reconsider your instictive "what the hell, no".  (In short, writing "inheritance" is *backwards* from reading).